# how to load a flutter app with existing isar db data?

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-isar

what I am trying to do:

I want that my flutter app comes with a predefined data set which is stored in isar.
I am already able to modify my isar db via app inputs. But I want that the app itself already contains a filled isar file.

My problem:
How can I add a isar db file to my app itself. Which I then can access on app start.

I could not find anything related to this in the Isar doc.
The only idea I had is to open an Isar instance inside my project folder, but giving a path of my project folder to the directory attribut:

```
final isar = await Isar.open(
  [SchemaName],
  directory: "lib/db/isar_files", //its a empty folder
);
```

Just gives me an error:

> Unhandled Exception: IsarError: Cannot open Environment: No such file or directory. Please make sure that the provided path is valid.

So I guess that is not the right way to do it?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the keyword I was looking for is a "prepopulated" db.
[This is an already existing Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491465/is-there-any-example-of-pre-populated-database-usage-in-flutter)

Now I need to find out how to write and embed a isar db file into my app :)